# Android Game object scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, touch, screen

I want to create some kind of a tower defense map using a background image which is fourth as large as the screen of the device (twice horizontal, twice vertical).

my question is, how can I do this best. I'm new to Android, just got some Java basics , and want ti try out some stuff.

I want the user to scroll over the entire map using their finger and want him to zoom in via 2 finger pinch, and of course the objects (towers, sprites) should stay were they are.

I've been searching for hours for now and only found answers like " use Scrollview". I just want a food for thought to get in the right way, maybe with some examples.

Comment: If you just got the Java basics, you should learn some more, about objects and functions, and then move on to GUI programming

Comment: i did some tutorials for android , creating apps like a notebook and a calculator.. and games with moving animated sprites with touchevents etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ImageView` and set appropriate `onTouchListener` where you will detect pinch-to-zoom gesture using `GestureDetector` and change view coordinates when user drags the finger.